# AWS s3 Uploading files on localhost, but not working in the real URL

Tags: php, apache, amazon-s3, file-upload, localhost

```
function setUploadAWS($ORIGEM, $DESTINO, $DIR) {

    $BUCKET = 'some-bucket';

    $ACCESS_KEY = "some-access-key";
    $SECRET_KEY = "some-secret-key";
    $credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials($ACCESS_KEY, $SECRET_KEY);

    try {

        $s3 = new S3Client([
            'version'     => 'latest',
            'region'      => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => $credentials
        ]);

        $result = $s3->putObject([
            'Bucket'     => $BUCKET,
            'Key'        => $DIR . $DESTINO,
            'SourceFile' => $ORIGEM,
        ]);
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
```

The aws code for uploading pictures is working to upload files through localhost, but it's not able to upload files to the system.

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? Do you get an error of some sort? Are your credentials correct?

Comment: I get an HTTP ERROR 500. The credentials are fine because it's working on localhost. I use CloudBerry Explorer to check the files I've uploaded.

Comment: Error 500 means useful errors in your webserver's log somewhere. Find them and you'll have your answer.

Comment: I put an option to display the error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception' with message 'Error executing "PutObject" on "https://storage-genesisgroup-dev.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/public/01102018122253.png"; AWS HTTP error: Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 [file]
It seems an access error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change parameters **allow_url_fopen** and **allow_url_include** to *On*:

```
allow_url_fopen= On
allow_url_include= On
```

The parameters are listed on php.ini.

```
Path = apache2/php.ini
```